# Can't add custom colors in Tailwind

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, tailwind-css

I'm trying to add a custom color:

```
extend: {
  colors: {
    'body-color': '#525B73'
  }
}
```

This breaks compilation with an error about built-in Tailwind classes not existing:

> The `bg-white` class does not exist.

Also tried `color: { bodyColor: '#525B73' }`, to no avail. This error vanishes if I remove my custom color. What's going on?

Below is a simplified version of my config file:

```
module.exports = {
  purge: [
    './components/**/*.vue',
    './layouts/**/*.vue',
    './pages/**/*.vue',
    './plugins/**/*.js'
  ],
  theme: {
    fontFamily: {
      'intro-black': ['intro-black', 'sans-serif']
    },
    container: {
      maxWidth: {
        lg: 'none'
      },
    },
    extend: {
      colors: {
        'body-color': '#525B73'
      },
      fontSize: {
        '30': '30px'
      },
      lineHeight: {
        '40': '40px'
      },
      height: {
        '60': '60px'
      },
      margin: {
        '100': '100px'
      },
      padding: {
        '40': '40px'
      },
      borderWidth: {
        '6': '6px'
      },
      zIndex: {
        '20000': '20000'
      },
      boxShadow: {
        '25': '0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)'
      },
      borderRadius: {
        '8': '8px'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT: as per @BoussadjraBrahim's comment I updated to Tailwind 2.x which replaces the main compilation problem with a minor "'body-color' class does not exist" problem.

Comment: I've tried it out in my project and it works fine

Comment: which version of tailwind are you using?

Comment: Not sure how to check that, in my `package.json` I see `"@nuxtjs/tailwindcss": "^3.4.2"`

Comment: `"@nuxtjs/tailwindcss": "^3.4.2"` is based on tailwind v1.x and `"@nuxtjs/tailwindcss": "^4.0.1" is based on tailwind 2.x, try to upgrade, it's probably a config issue

Comment: Thanks @BoussadjraBrahim! I updated accordingly (I had to update Nuxt too). Now I don't get an error when defining my custom color. However I still cannot use my color as if I try I get this error: "The 'body-color' class does not exist"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add a custom color it will applied to any colorable property like background, text, border and gradient ..., so if you define a color named `body-color` it will be available as :

`bg-body-color` : for background color

`text-body-color` : for text color

`border-body-color` : for border color

and so on

I recommend to give an appropriate name like `primary` or `blue-gray` instead of `body-color`

Comment: I've been facing the same issue. I have added colors in `tailwind.config.js` but it does not apply even when I use `bg-very-dark-blue`.
```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["*"],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        'very-dark-blue': 'hsl(233, 47%, 7%)',
        'dark-desaturated-blue': 'hsl(244, 38%, 16%)',
        'soft-viole': 'hsl(277, 64%, 61%)'
      }
    },
  }
```

Comment: How do you use the color class? please give me an example

Comment: Oh, I figured it out. I forgot to run cli script to modify the `output.css`.